# Chrome pending on images, javascript streamlining?

Tags: image, google-chrome, loading

There has been very little changed to this [page](http://pocketfulofdublin.com/relaxing-here.html) since it just recently stopped loading properly on Chrome.

If you click the link three times things usually load up fine. I've looked through the developer tools and can see that it's hanging up on the js the first load. The second load has pending on most/all of the .jpgs, and then finally another click/load works.

I know it's a heavy site, but the other pages are fine, in terms of actually loading and not just going idle, and this loads well enough in Firefox. I don't think this site is even the largest of the pages in terms of images and video.

I've gone through others solutions to this problem by changing the "https" and renaming files incase an adblocker was causing it, but nothing seems to work.

Any idea of what in the page is causing the issue?